# Dynamic Inheritance - Java

Tags: java, generics, jpa

Dynamic Inheritance

I have a situation where I want a class (which is a JPA entity) to be able to extend either class A or class B dynamically. My thought was to use Generics, but it looks like generics doesn’t support this. For example:

```
@Entity
public abstract class Resource() {
...
}

@Entity
public abstract class Snapshot() {
...
}

public abstract class CommonRS<R extends Resource, S extends Snapshot> {
/* This is the class that I want to dynamically assign Inheritance to. */
...
}

@Entity
public class FeedResource extends CommonRS<Resource> {
...
}

@Entity
public class FeedSnapshot extends CommonRS<Snapshot> {
...
}
```

The reason I want to do this is that FeedResource must Inherit from Resource and FeedSnapshot must inherit from Snapshot because both classes are using the JPA join strategy `InheritanceType.JOINED` and are persisted to different tables, however they both share common attributes and I would like them to be able to inherit those common attributes.

I understand that I can I could use @Embeddable on CommonRS and the Embed it in both FeedResource and FeedSnapshot.

Since Java doesn’t support multiple inheritance, I can’t see any other way to do this other than using Embeddable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you do it

```
@MappedSuperClass
public abstract class Base() {
...
// put your common attributes here
}

@Entity
public abstract class Resource() extends Base{
...
}

@Entity
public abstract class Snapshot() extends Base {
...
}

public abstract class CommonRS<R extends Base> {
...
}

@Entity
public class FeedResource extends CommonRS<Resource> {
...
}

@Entity
public class FeedSnapshot extends CommonRS<Snapshot> {
...
}
```

**UPDATE**

Another solution can be implementing same interface (if common inheritance cannot be achieved). In that case @MappedSuperClass annotation should be used on actual base classes.

```
@Entity
public abstract class Resource() extends BaseIntf {
...
}

@Entity
public abstract class Snapshot() extends BaseIntf {
...
}

public abstract class CommonRS<R extends BaseIntf> {
...
}

@Entity
public class FeedResource extends CommonRS<Resource> {
...
}

@Entity
public class FeedSnapshot extends CommonRS<Snapshot> {
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. One thing I forgot to mention in my example above is that Resource and Snapshot can't extend "Base" as there are many "Bases" that they may have to extends. That's why I was hoping to have CommonRS dynamically extend whatever "Base" I needed to.

I coming to the conclusion the only way to do it is by using Embeddable.

Comment: Try to implement the same interface instead of extending Base class. Should work the same way